# Parsing a file and use perl regex to match fields in the file

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, text-parsing

I have a file with the format bellow and I need to use Perl and regex to get the values to insert a database. I try to use regex, but I have errors. Follow the script I use to get the first value:

```
# line 1
open(my $fin, "<", "input.txt") 
    or die "cannot open < input.txt: $!";
my $line1 = <$fin>;
chomp $line1;
print "$line\n";

my ($codigo, $nome) = ($line1 =~ m/^((\d)+)\s[\S]\s(([\s\d\w])+)$/);
print "#$codigo#$nome#\n";

# line 2
$line2 = <$fin>;
chomp $line2;
..
```

But I don´t see the correct value of "codigo" and "nome".

The format of file is:

```
84404167 - NAME ONE OF SILVA
R NONONONO, 143334, HOUSE - REGION - CITY - 81280400
Res: (22)5555.4543 Cel: (33)5555.8659 Ou: 
Início: 17/12/2013 - Data de aniv.: 23/02/1955
Crédito: 1440 - Crédito Disponível: 1152 - Status: ATIVA 

96071311 - NAME SECOND OF JOSE
R SECRET ADDRESS NONONNO, 433, ap 232 b azaleia - fazendinha - CURITIBA - 81320420
Res:  Cel: (22)5555.9776 Ou: (33)5555.2352
Início: 22/01/2015 - Data de aniv.: 10/05/1981
Crédito: 764 - Crédito Disponível: 516 - Status: ATIVA
```

Comment: If you had `use strict` and `use warnings` turned on, you'd get a compilation error about `$line`. It's not the source of your problem, but still.

Comment: The real problem is that you were a little overzealous with the parentheses, and you ended up with too many capture groups as a result. `my @matches = $_ =~ m/^((\d)+)\s[\S]\s(([\s\d\w])+)$/; dd(\@matches);` produces `[84404167, 7, "NAME ONE OF SILVA", "A"]`. Also, in the future, instead of saying that you don't see the correct value, you should provide the output you _are_ seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regex you can use `split` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fin, "<", "abc.txt" or die "cannot open input.txt: $!";

while (my $line1 = <$fin>)
{
    chomp $line1;
    if ($. == 1)     # line 1
    {   
        my ($codigo, $nome) = split (/\s*-\s*/, $line1);
        print "codigo: $codigo nome: $nome\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
codigo: 84404167 nome: NAME ONE OF SILVA
```

Comment: You could split on `/\s*-\s*/` to clean up those surrounding spaces.

Comment: @MattJacob: Done. Thanks! :)

Comment: You beat me to the answer by about 15 seconds. My answer was essentially the same, except with the `\s*`, so no need to post it again. ;-)